# Change package.json file dependency on the basis of production and development

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, package.json, electron-packager

I want to change my electron version in **package.json** file on the basis of the **production** and **development** stage.
If my project in the **development** phase then it will take **electron 11.2.0** version and in **production** my electron version must be **electron 3.1.1**. Is there any way to do this task or apply this condition on my **package.json** file?

Comment: Electron v11.2.0 and v3.1.1 are **drastically** different in terms of API changes. Are you completely sure you want to be hopping around versions like that?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah.

You can add a `devDependencies` object to your **package.json**. Also when you install packages to your project you can install them with the `--save-dev` flag to automatically do that.

It will look like this:

```json
"name": "my_package",
"version": "1.0.0",
"dependencies": {
  "my_dep": "^1.0.0",
  "another_dep": "~2.2.0"
},
"devDependencies" : {
  "my_test_framework": "^3.1.0".
  "another_dev_dep": "1.0.0 - 1.2.0"
}
```

More information can be found in the official documentation for npm.

https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file